# Does <img> have to be wrapped/contained within a block element?

Tags: html, image, standards

In the world of accessibility, there are times when I have no idea what I'm doing. Obviously, it doesn't HAVE to be in a block element, but I have this:

```
<div>
   <h2>
   <img>
   <p>
   <p>
   <h2>
   <img>
   <p>
   <p>
</div>
```

in which the img would be floated to the right, and I was told "Per standards, an img needs contained  in a block level element, not allowed to be inline anymore." I'm hoping someone can point me to some kind of reference that this is either true or false, because I can't seem to find one on my own.

Comment: This is not required at all. It can be inline and it doesn't matter. In some cases your styling would be easier achieved using a block element, but those cases revolve around captions and other elements involved with the image.

Comment: Yeah, everything I'm seeing normally suggests, at most, adding display:block; style to the img. Would you agree?

Comment: Display block I have found to be very useful to shaping the image correctly. I don't fully understand it I feel, but the way I imagine it is that the image is a floating point piece that hovers above the code. Granted it doesn't act that way exactly, but the way it lays isn't perfect and easy to move unless you do a display block. (hopefully this makes sense...)